# How can I tell if a macOS app is native or just a wrap around a website?

Tags: macos, applications, swift, documentation

I've got a cookie notice when launching an app for the first time on macOS, which I didn't know was a thing.

Looking at the processes running, I see 3 processes spawned by the app. One looks like a regular packaged app, but one reads `Pocket Casts Web Content (<PID>)` and its name is just the url leading to the webapp version of the app. I've only seen `Web Content` processes being used as browser helpers, and can't find anything in the Apple docs.

Comment: Technically speaking, the app is native.  It just so happens that all the content including the UI is sourced from the web.

Comment: could you expand on that? Are you saying that is a swift app with a single web view? I would also welcome any links about the "Web Content" process if it's something you're familiar with

Comment: A wrapper is in and of itself  native code; it has to be. What happens inside the wrapper can be anything from pulling a website that prints “Hello World”, a link to a database that runs queries and presents data locally or scrapes a website for the mobile formatted version.